# Unable to install Hybridworker extension seamlessly

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-automation

I have a good code to create VM and also install the Hybrid worker and Hybrid Worker extension however it gives an error when trying to install the hybrid worker extension.

```
$maxRetryCount = 3
$retryCount = 0
$retryIntervalSeconds = 120
do {
    $testvm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Status | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "winvm1" }
    if ($testvm.PowerState -ne "VM running") {
        $retryCount ++
        Write-Output "INFORMATION:: Waiting for Man VM to be operational. Retries : $($retryCount) of $($maxRetryCount)"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryIntervalSeconds
    } else {
        Write-Output "INFORMATION:: winvm1 is in running state."
        break
    }
} while ($retryCount -lt $maxRetryCount)

if ($testvm.PowerState -ne "VM running") {
    Write-Error "VM not running."
}

$HW1 = Get-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorkerGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -AutomationAccountName $aaname -Name "hwrwinvm1"
$getHW1 = Get-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker -ResourceGroupName  $resourcegroupname -AutomationAccountName $aaname -HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName $HW1.Name | Where-Object { $_.VmResourceId -like $testvm.id}
if(!$getHW1){
    [guid]$worker1 = [guid]::NewGuid()

    Write-Output "ATTEMPTING:: Hybrid Worker Creation for  $($testvm.Name)"
    try {
        $hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
            ResourceGroupName               = $resourcegroupname
            AutomationAccountName           = $aaname
            VmResourceId                    = $testvm.Id
            HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName    = $HW1.Name
            Name                            = $worker1
        }
        # Attempt to create a new Hybrid Worker
        $null = New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration
    } catch {
        Write-Error "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

if(!$getHW1.Ip){
    #create AutomationURI
    $token = Get-AzBearerToken
    $automationurl1 = "https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/${aaName}?api-version=2021-06-22"
    $settingsMan = @{
        AutomationAccountURL = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $automationurl1 -Headers @{ "Authorization" = $token } -Method Get).properties.AutomationHybridServiceUrl
    }

    try {
        $installextension = @{
            ResourceGroupName           = $testvm.ResourceGroupName
            Location                    = $testvm.Location
            VMName                      = $testvm.Name
            Name                        = "HybridWorkerExtension"
            Publisher                   = "Microsoft.Azure.Automation.HybridWorker"
            ExtensionType               = "HybridWorkerForWindows"
            TypeHandlerVersion          = "1.1"
            Settings                    = $settingsMan
            EnableAutomaticUpgrade      = $true
        }
    
        # Attempt to set the VM extension
        Set-AzVMExtension @installextension
    } catch {
        Write-Error "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}else{
    Write-Warning "Extension installed"
}
```

it comes back with error:

```
 . '/home/vsts/work/1/s/SCRIPTS/PIPELINE/failover.ps1' -subscriptionId …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | An error occurred while setting the VM extension: Long running operation
     | failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'VM has reported a failure
     | when processing extension 'HybridWorkerExtension' (publisher
     | 'Microsoft.Azure.Automation.HybridWorker' and type
     | 'HybridWorkerForWindows'). Error message: "[Internal Error] The Hybrid
     | Worker Extension failed to execute:
     | System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
     | the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be
     | resolved:
     | 'XXXX.jrds.usge.azure-automation.us'   
     | at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
     | asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
     | System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
     | ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
     | System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
```

I am sure that this works sometimes, and when it does, it give the message that the extension has not been provisioned when I check hybridworkers in the automation account. However when I check the VM it shows the extension installed.

[image: Azure screenshot]

Comment: Hi there, To isolate the issue, have you tested to run the script from your local machine? If the issue is reproducible on your local machine, it can rule out the cause by MS-hosted agent environment of you pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Ayandaezekiel, Have you got a chance to check the answer below? May I know whether this error is caused by Azure Pipeline environment or the extension installation itself? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
An error occurred while setting the VM extension: Long running operation
     | failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'VM has reported a failure
     | when processing extension
```

The error occurs when incorrect resource details are provided or if the necessary resource isn't available to create the `HybridWorkerExtension`.

Here is the updated code to create `Hybrid Worker Group` , `Hybrid Worker` and `HybridWorkerExtension`.

```
# Your existing code to create Hybrid Worker
$rgname = '<Resource-Group-Name>'
$AutomateAcc = '<Automation-Account>'
$hybridWorkerGroupName = 'Venkat'
$workerName = New-Guid

# Provide the full resource ID of your VM
$vmResourceId = '/subscriptions/<sub-ID>/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VenaktVM'

# Create a new Hybrid Worker Group configuration

New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorkerGroup -AutomationAccountName $AutomateAcc -Name $hybridWorkerGroupName -ResourceGroupName $rgname

# Create a new Hybrid Worker configuration
$hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $rgname
    AutomationAccountName = $aaname
    VmResourceId = $vmResourceId
    HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName = $hybridWorkerGroupName
    Name = $workerName
}

# Add the new Hybrid Worker to the group
New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration

$settings = @{
    "AutomationAccountURL"  = "https://03701b48-9c64-49a1-ab68-058d73996c8d.jrds.eus.azure-automation.net/automationAccounts/03701b48-9c64-49a1-ab68-058d73996c8d";
};

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Location "East US" -VMName "VenaktVM" -Name "HybridWorkerExtension" -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Automation.HybridWorker" -ExtensionType HybridWorkerForLinux -TypeHandlerVersion 1.1 -Settings $settings -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true
```

**Hybrid Worker Creation**

[image]

**HybridWorkerExtension Installation**

[image]

Reference:
[New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorkerGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationhybridrunbookworkergroup?view=azps-11.0.0)

[New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationhybridrunbookworker?view=azps-11.0.0)

[Deploy an extension-based Windows or Linux User Hybrid Runbook Worker in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/extension-based-hybrid-runbook-worker-install?tabs=linux,bicep-template)